# If then statement in R - replacing based on value

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a very large file where I have merged two customer databases.   The key is the ID.   Where the customer name did not match it shows an NA.   I need to accomplish a simple if/then statement where if there is "NA" in column NAME_1 the DESIRED OUTCOME NAME is what is in NAME_2, else use what is in NAME_1

I attempted the following code but get errors

`df <- df %>% if (df$NAME_1 == "NA") rename(df$NAME_1 == df$NAME_2)`

[image]

Comment: Would there be any cases where NAME_1 and NAME_2 differ but NAME_1 is not NA (e.g. one is "Bob" the other is "Robert"

Comment: great question but no....there are only NA values

Comment: Then why not just use NAME_2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ifelse` from `base` R,

```
df$'DESIRED OUTCOME NAME' = ifelse(is.na(df$NAME_1), df$NAME_2, df$NAME_1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply done with

```
df$NAME_1[is.na(df$NAME_1)] <- df$NAME_2[is.na(df$NAME_1)]
```

This is just subsetting the values in each of the vectors to elements in positions where it is NA in NAME_1

I'd prefer to do this with a data.table rather than data.frame, then you can do

```
df[is.na(NAME_1), NAME_1 := NAME_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution with dummy data acording to the info you supplied:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,6,3,5,6,2,8,9),
                 NAME_1 = c(NA, "STEVE", NA, "JULIE", "BOB", "AMY", NA, "BRUCE"),
                 NAME_2 = c("MARY", "STEVE", "JAN", "JULIE", "BOB", "AMY", "FRANK", "BRUCE"))

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(NEW_COLUMN = ifelse(is.na(NAME_1), NAME_2, NAME_1))
```

Comment: @DataScienceDave I altered the answer with dummy data (the error indicates that df has not been defined/declared) ... "df" is the dataframe holding the values of interest, possibly you are using another name for your data.frame!?

Comment: @DataScienceDave please consider to accept or upvote my answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry it worked fine as I had a typo.    How would I create an additional column name with the final name instead of renaming the NAME_1 column

Comment: @DataScienceDave just use a diferent name in the mutate call.. I altered the anwer for the code to generate a new column called "NEW_COLUMN"

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the simplest solution would be to use `dplyr::coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(`DESIRED OUTCOME NAME` = coalesce(NAME_1, NAME_2))

#OR

df$`DESIRED OUTCOME NAME` <- coalesce(NAME_1, NAME_2)

  ID NAME_1 NAME_2 DESIRED OUTCOME NAME
1  1   <NA>   MARY                 MARY
2  6  STEVE  STEVE                STEVE
3  3   <NA>    JAN                  JAN
4  5  JULIE  JULIE                JULIE
5  6    BOB    BOB                  BOB
6  2    AMY    AMY                  AMY
7  8   <NA>  FRANK                FRANK
8  9  BRUCE  BRUCE                BRUCE
```